# How do i show: $\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x\ {\sin^{2n} x}\ dx}{{{\sin^{2n} x}}+{\cos^{2n} x}}= \frac{\pi^2}{4}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I tried by substituting $u=\tan x$ but it wasn't so useful. Have you got any hint?

Comment: The substitution $u = \tan x$ doesn't work because : $$\dfrac{\pi}{2} \in [0, \pi]$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that for the substitution $u = \pi - x$ we have :
$$\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{x \sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{(\pi - u) \sin^{2n} u}{\sin^{2n} u + \cos^{2n} u} \mathrm{d}u$$
then :
$$2 \int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{x \sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x = \pi \int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x$$
The function :
$$f(x) = \dfrac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x}$$
is symmetric by $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ then :
$$\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x = 2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x$$
We deduce that :
$$\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{x \sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x = \pi \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x$$
With the substitution $u = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - x$ :
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\cos^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x$$
and now the sum of the two integrals :
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\cos^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
We deduce that :
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$$
then :
$$\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{x \sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Comment: +1. Do you mind finishing it? Thanks.

Comment: I will try. I just noticed that $x$ is not compatible with $\sin$ and $\cos$ so i it will be better to use this substitution to make more compatible.

Comment: In the last line, you can use a similar substitution to what you used earlier $x \to \pi/2 - x$  which makes the new integrand $$I = \pi \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} dx = \pi \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^{2n} x}{\sin^{2n} x + \cos^{2n} x} dx$$ then add the two integrals together and divide by two.

Comment: Ok it's done. What a nice game of substitution.